# How to ship TensorFlow with my app?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm building an app with C++ and I want to include an ML classifier model that I've built with TensorFlow. App will be built for different operating systems. Is there any way to ship TensorFlow with my app so people don't have to install TensorFlow by themselves on their machines?

My other option is to make my own neural network implementation in C++ and just read weights and biases from saved TensorFlow model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using freeze_graph to package your graphdef and weights into a single file, and then follow the label_image C++ example for how to load and run the resulting GraphDef file:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc#L140